# Keep text of a text field in a modal view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, modalviewcontroller

Hi so I have a text field in a Modal ViewController that adjusts a TabBarItem title in a different view. The problem is that the text field clears once you leave the Modal ViewController. How can I keep the text in the text field so that when I return it is still there?

Comment: Keep a reference to your modal view controller and redisplay it instead of creating a new one every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you present a view controller modally, you're instantiating a new one (and so is the textfield that's why it's empty)

You can easily solve this by adding an NSString property to the view controller you're presenting modally (to the .h file)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
```

(you also need to synthesize it)

and in your viewDidLoad set the textfield's text

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextField.text = self.text;
}
```

By keeping it like this it will do nothing because your "text" property is nil,
You need to set it just before you call `presentModalViewController:animated:`

```
// "controller" being your modal view controller
controller.text = @"The tile you're keeping somewhere";
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: really appreciate the answer and the reasoning behind it. thanks man!